# Will time.process_time() sum all CPU times from subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, time, scikit-learn, subprocess

I want to find a way to get accumulated CPU times of all subprocess in python, I tried time.process_time() in the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets


def sub_process():
    t0 = time.time()
    t1 = time.process_time()
    x = 0
    for i in range(1000000000):
        x+=i
    print(time.time()-t0)
    print(time.process_time()-t1)

def main_process():
    process_list = []
    for _ in range(2):
        tmp_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=sub_process)
        process_list.append(tmp_process)
    for process in process_list:
        process.start()
    for process in process_list:
        process.join()

main_t_0 = time.time()
main_t_1 = time.process_time()
main_process()
print(time.time()-main_t_0)
print(time.process_time()-main_t_1)
```

And got the following result:

60.51823401451111

60.518644068

61.03675556182861

61.037412923

61.048630237579346

0.00870562100000001

which indicates that time.process_time() does not contain the processing time used by sub_process. However, if I tried the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sklearn
from sklearn import datasets

main_t_0 = time.time()
main_t_1 = time.process_time()
A = datasets.make_spd_matrix(10000)
print(time.time()-main_t_0)
print(time.process_time()-main_t_1)
```

The result would be:

185.01790952682495

3086.4627873910003

I can see from the terminal that when running datasets.make_spd_matrix, there also exist several subprocess, but this time, time.process_time() seems to sum their CPU time all up. Could someone tell me why these two cases are different?

Comment: Does `datasets.make_spd_matrix` actually have subprocesses or multiple threads?

Comment: Oh I have solved this problem, make_spd_matrix has multiple threads (but not subprocesses), I thought it has subprocesses because each thread has a unique PID in htop, while these PIDs are actually SPIDs. Thank you anyway!